# OOM Error w/ javadoc plugin -Xmx doesn't work!

Tags: java, maven-2, javadoc

I'm trying to run javadoc on a multi-module Maven project and I keep getting OutOfMemory Error no matter how high I set the heap. I've even tried upping the pergen space. Is there a way to find the root cause? I suspect some sort of recursive reference in a Javadoc comment but the project is so huge it'll take days/weeks/months to sift thru.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 1):

don't set -Xms and -Xmx (they will increase the memory of the maven process), use the [minmemory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#minmemory) and [maxmemory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#maxmemory) options of the [maven javadoc plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) to increase the memory of the forked javadoc process

```
   <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
             <minmemory>128m</minmemory>
             <maxmemory>1024m</maxmemory>
             ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </reporting>
```

Comment: That almost looks like it wants to work. I don't know why but the process gets stuck when I set the heap in MAVEN_OPTS to 2048. (Ctrl+C won't even terminate and I must send signal 9 from another terminal.) I just backed it down and also tried your parameter and now it completes. I still have another project that throws OOM. I'm setting via the cmd line using -D. I gotta try inlining in my pom as I believe this other project uses a dated version of the Javadoc plugin.

Comment: Nope, I just tried this from the cmd line and it STILL throws the OOM:
mvn -Dmaxmemory=1024m org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.6:javadoc